# Getting a higher voltage from TL431 in a crowbar circuit

Tags: zener, over-voltage-protection, tl431

I want to protect a circuit from overvoltage using crowbar circuit, the input voltage shouldn't get above 50 V.

- TL431 output is 36 V max, can a zener diode in series like schematic below protect the TL431? (is the circuit below correct)
- Should I add the triac gate trigger voltage to the set voltage?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWrQZq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[BT139 datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/848/bt139-600-1286846.pdf)

[TL431 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried a simulation?

Comment: @Andyaka No, not yet. I need to get use to using the simulator more often...

Comment: Do you really want to short out the supply abruptly or simply block it with current limiting softly such as a Zener and PTC . There is thermal protection already. Is this a real need for device failure protection?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The voltage goes directly to a transistor collector with 60V VCE limit, max current passing through is 10A. I'm not familiar with zener and PTC protection circuit. is it faster or more reliable?

Comment: You may need to define your 10A load better in terms of dynamic changes Energy=1/2LI^2 needs to be absorbed if open suddenly for overvoltage protection (OVP).  Generally a Joule rated MOV or TVS can be used for OVP. These behave like Zener clamps but for this purpose. When the voltage is steady over limit, then a current limiting PTC ceramic part is used also with a positive temp. coefficient so it can recover automatically  Otherwise diode clamps to the input voltage are often used.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm not blocking the momentary surge voltage, the voltage might be high and still connected to the input, can I still use MOV for this case?

Comment: Yes a PTC is the general abbreviation for the brandname Polyfuse which may be used with any voltage limiting clamp by choosing the holding current threshold. They are n't intended to be precise parts so a temperature rise to 85'C is expected to increase the series resistance sharply to limit current determined by the voltage clamp. The power dissipation must be considered in all parts and your crowbar must be used if VI=P is too high to be reasonable. then the the PTC limits current and a power cycle to reset the SCR below holding current threshold.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 So in combination of crowbar and PTC, this cycle of cooling and heating up will keep the current flow in the triac which will cause heat, correct?

Comment: For a DC power driver only an SCR is needed which has a negative resistance and thus drops voltage to ~1V + IfRs and if the OV is removed and then current drops , it cools resistance drops a couple orders of magnitude to the rated R value and it operates normal but all maximum values must be observed and not exceeded

Comment: Of course, you could always choose a better transistor with higher voltage rating, and then you don't want a transient to false trigger a crowbar, so you might add a 1ms RC filter

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for all the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to 'set' the TL431 to your desired nominal crowbar voltage. Read the TL431 datasheet and look at the block diagram to understand *why*.

[image]

You also likely will want to reduce R3 considerably. The TL431 needs 1mA, so maybe a couple hundred ohms. Otherwise current will flow thorough the gate unnecessarily before it is supposed to trigger. Probably not enough to trigger it, even under corner conditions, but there's no real advantage.

Agree with Andy, set up a free simulator such as LTspice (you may have to add the models for the parts) and test this yourself, then ask questions if it does not make sense.

Comment: "*You want to 'set' the TL431 to your desired nominal crowbar voltage. Read the TL431 datasheet and look at the block diagram to understand why.*" I don't get it...

Comment: What relationship can you divine between the cathode voltage and the op-amp inputs?

Comment: REF input is independent from the cathode voltage?

Comment: Correct. So it is comparing the divider voltage directly to the reference of 2.495V nominal.

Comment: So the zener in series is needed and I just have to set the TL431 to 50V?

Comment: Yes, to both and as I said about R3.

Comment: Thanks, just about the gate trigger voltage; should I count that too and set the TL431 voltage to 49.3V?

Comment: The gate trigger voltage appears at the cathode. How does that influence the REF input? Not at all .

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answers, a TRIAC usually needs a current pulse to fully turn on. You could add a PNP transistor at the output of the zener diode, which discharges a previously charged capacitor to the gate of the TRIAC.
Here is a small simulation:

[image: circuit]

The cyan color depicts the current through the TRIAC.
[image: waveform]

Comment: I couldn't find a single source mentioning this in crowbar circuits, thank you.